# Cómo puedo eliminar espacios en blanco en Bash

Tags: bash, unix

Tengo un archivo de texto con varias palabras que se encuentran separadas por varios espacios en blanco entre sí y, al mismo tiempo, con líneas en blanco entre las palabras.

Es algo tal que así, solo que además de esto hay palabras en diferentes filas con varios espacios entre filas (perdonad pero no sabía cómo poner esto último aquí):

```
Esto            es      un texto de     ejemplo
```

Me gustaría reemplazar cada espacio en blanco (ya sea espacio, tabulación, nueva línea...) con un caracter de nueva línea ("single newline character").

He probado con `tr '[:blank:]' '\n'` y lo único que he conseguido es que cada palabra me aparezca en una fila nueva, pero los espacios en blanco extra entre filas no desaparecen. Es decir, necesito que las múltiples líneas que separan las filas desaparezcan para quedarme solo con una lista de palabras.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo un archivo de texto llamado `prueba.txt` como el siguiente:

```
Esto            es      un texto de     ejemplo varios espacios repetidos

Esta            Varios tabs repetidos
es
otra linea



varios saltos de linea repetidos texto
```

podemos usar el mismo comando [`tr`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/tr1.html) pero de la siguiente forma

```
cat prueba.txt | tr " \t" "\n" | tr -s "\n"
```

**Explicación**:

- Con `tr " \t" "\n"` reemplazamos espacios y tabuladores por salto de línea `\n`
- A la salida del comando anterior le corremos: `tr -s "\n"` la opción `-s` (squeeze) comprime múltiples `\n` en uno solo

**Nota:** Podemos evitar el uso del `cat` si este mismo comando la ejecutamos así: `tr " \t" "\n" < prueba.txt | tr -s "\n"`

Y obtendríamos una salida como la siguiente:

```
Esto
es
un
texto
de
ejemplo
varios
espacios
repetidos
Esta
Varios
tabs
repetidos
es
otra
linea
varios
saltos
de
linea
repetidos
texto
```

Comment: Perfecto! funciona

Comment: Buena respuesta. @aprendiz si te funcionó, es recomendable que aceptes la respuesta: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

¿Y qué tal si intentas que Grep busque todas las palabras e imprima cada una en una línea?

```
grep -Eo '\S*' fichero
```

`\S` coincide con todos los caracteres que no son espacios (o tabuladores, líneas en blanco...).

Ejemplo:

```
$ cat fichero
hola             como estas     yo
bien ¿y tú?     pues    tirando
olé
```

Probemos:

```
$ grep -Eo '\S*' fichero
hola
como
estas
yo
bien
¿y
tú?
pues
tirando
olé
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tenemos una cadena, por ejemplo `s`, podemos hacer:

```
s=" Esto es     un texto       de     ejemplo"
texto=( ${s} ) 
texto=${texto[*]}
echo .."${texto}"..
..Esto es un texto de ejemplo..
```

Lo mismo pero simplificado:

```
s=" Esto es     un texto       de     ejemplo"; s=( $s ); s=${s[*]}
echo $s
```

Entonces tenemos el texto sin espacios repetidos.

Comment: Interesante, pero no responde a la pregunta puesto que el autor especificó: *Me gustaría reemplazar cada espacio en blanco (ya sea espacio, tabulación, nueva línea...) con un caracter de nueva línea ("single newline character").*. Y con tu respuesta el código saldría en la misma línea